# Retrieve data from two table

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I have two tables `tblRegistration(id,name,program,regdno,address)` and `tblDue(id,regdno,amountdue)`. What I want is to pass regdno from a `textbox` and then retrieve the `name`, `program` values form `tblRegistration` and `amountdue` from `tblDue`.

What i tried is ,

```
select t1.name,t1.program, t2.amountdue 
from tblRegistration as t1 
inner join tblDue as t2 on t2.regdno= t1.regdno;
```

It returns all values having same `regdno` in both tables.

Help me on getting those values only whose `regdno` I provide from textbox.

Sorry for the language. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifiy your query sql like this:

```
 select t1.name,t1.program, t2.amountdue from tblRegistration as t1 inner join tblDue as t2 on t2.regdno= t1.regdno
 where t1.regdno=yourvaluetestbox;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't any relationship between Registration and Due table. you mustn't join these table. You can Simple run two query to fetch data. the first, from Registration table and the second, from Due table:

```
select * from tblReg where regdno=...;
select * from tblDue where regdno=...;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.name,t1.program, t2.amountdue FROM tblRegistration AS t1 INNER JOIN tblDue AS t2 ON t2.regdno = t1.regdno
WHERE t1.regdno = 'TextBoxValue';
```

Please let me know if you need any more clarification.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use Where clause at the end of your your query

```
Where t1.regdno ='TextBox Text' and t2.regdno = 'TextBox Text'
```

in place of using regdno in two tables you should remove regdno from tblDue Table and Add a Foreign key reference in tblDue for tblRegisteration  add regid in tblDue
new query will be :

`select t1.name,t1.program, t2.amountdue from tblRegistration as t1 
inner join tblDue as t2 on t2.regid= t1.id 
where t1.regdno ='TextBox Text'`